# How to calculate $E[X^{2}]$ and $E[X^{3}]$ when given a probability generating function?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

I have been given a probability generating function $G_{X}(s)$. The expected value of $X$ is $$E[X] = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}G_{X}(1).$$
However, how do I calculate $E[X^{2}]$ and $E[X^{3}]$?

Comment: The answer is contained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function   what did you not understand?

Comment: But such comment could be made to most of the questions on this site?

Comment: The key part of @kjetilbhalvorsen 's comment is "what part did you not understand"? Without that elaboration, all we can do is point you to the appropriate definitions and references and hope for the best. But if you elaborate on where you're stuck, then it's possible to point out how and why some particular step is true, or whatever other clarification is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken, $$E[X^{2}] = \underbrace{E[X(X-1)]}_{=\ E[X^{2}] - E[X]} + E[X] = \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d}s^{2}} G_{X}(1) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}G_{X}(1).$$

Similar idea can be used to obtain $E[X^{3}]$, I guess.